# Use EventEmitter in ES6 class

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, ecmascript-6, eventemitter

I am trying to get the EventEmitter in my own class running in ES6:

```
"use strict";
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class Client extends EventEmitter{

    constructor(token, client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri, code){
        super();
        this.token = token;
        this.client_id = client_id;
        this.client_secret = client_secret;
        this.redirect_uri = redirect_uri;
        this.code = code;
    }

    eventTest(){
        this.emit("event");
        console.log(this.token);
    }
}

let testClient = new Client(1,2,3,4,5);

testClient.eventTest();
testClient.on('event', () => {console.log('triggerd!')} );
```

but the event is doing nothing ^^

Without ES6 i got it working with this code:

```
var util = require('util');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

var Client = function(credentials) {
    var self = this;

    function eventTest() {
        self.emit('event');
    }
};

util.inherits(Client, EventEmitter);
```

Does someone know how to do it right in ES6?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;`?

Comment: [here's a bunch of good examples](https://gist.github.com/gdi2290/bec4889e0a5785cae2a9), or specifically [this one](https://gist.github.com/gdi2290/bec4889e0a5785cae2a9#file-pseudo-classical-es6-js)

Comment: @nem035 I already found the collection, but I didn't understood how to make an event. The examples just show how to create a function inside a class :/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Events are synchronous - you're firing it before you are listening. Use

```
const testClient = new Client(1,2,3,4,5);
testClient.on('event', () => {console.log('triggered!')} );
testClient.eventTest();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is such a dumb mistake.

Comment: @Alaska The occurrence of events is usually non-deterministic and thus asynchronous, unless your code emits them itself. So I wouldn't call it a dumb mistake :D

Comment: bergi's answer works. Just wanted to add that using an EventEmitter for synchronous code can be considered an anti-pattern.  The nature of EventEmitter lies in its ability to deal with asynchronous events.

Like user3674318 mentioned, consider making your method asynchronous so that the user of the abstraction can use it as expected.

[Node.js Design Patterns Chapter 3][1] is a terrific resource for understanding the Observer pattern.


  [1]: https://www.nodejsdesignpatterns.com/

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the browser w/o a library?

Comment: @chovy If you mean using the nodejs `EventEmitter`, no that is not possible

Answer (score 3):

You could use `process.nextTick()` to make you code asynchronous. Afterwards everything will work as expected. This is the note from the node documentation:

> The `process.nextTick()` method adds the callback to the "next tick queue". Once the current turn of the event loop turn runs to completion, all callbacks currently in the next tick queue will be called.

```
eventTest(){
    process.nextTick(() => {
        this.emit("event");
    });
    console.log(this.token);
}
```