# Node.js EventEmitter `on` event cannot "see" class property

Tags: javascript, eventemitter

This is a follow-up to my [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55196644/node-js-eventemitter-on-event-is-not-responding-to-emit-actions). In that question, I've defined an `index.js` file that includes an `on` event handler. I've since updated the `index.js` file to look like this:

**index.js**

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const Student = require('./student');
const Whiteboard = require('./whiteboard');

class Classroom {
  constructor() {
    this.whiteboard = new Whiteboard();
  }

  async function start() {
    eventEmitter.on('newListener', (event, listener) => {
      console.log(`Added ${event} listener.`);
    });

    eventEmitter.on('handRaised', (question) => {
      console.log(question);
      this.whiteboard.write(question);
    });

    for (let i=0; i<10; i++) {
      let student = new Student(`Student #${i+1}`);
      student.attend();
    }
  }
}
```

When I run my app, the line with `this.whiteboard.write(question);` generates an error. That error is: `Cannot read property 'write' of undefined`. I've confirmed that `this.whiteboard` is undefined. My question is, how do I get access to class properties on events?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it a problem you have `eventEmitter` and `EventEmitter`? I suspect the async `start()` gets called before the `constructor()` function.

Comment: Please show how you use the class `Classroom` and `start()`.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a problem with using `this.whiteboard`, but your class definition is strange, actually I would expect `SyntaxError` by the method definition.

Try to change your code like this:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const Student = require('./student');
const Whiteboard = require('./whiteboard');

const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter(); /* create an emitter instance */

class Classroom {
  constructor() {
    this.whiteboard = new Whiteboard();
  }

  async start() { /* no 'function' here */
    eventEmitter.on('newListener', (event, listener) => {
      console.log(`Added ${event} listener.`);
    });

    eventEmitter.on('handRaised', (question) => {
      console.log(question);
      this.whiteboard.write(question);
    });

    for (let i=0; i<10; i++) {
      let student = new Student(`Student #${i+1}`);
      student.attend();
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** instancing of `EventEmitter`

Comment: I think it should be this way: `const EventEmitter = require('events'); const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();` and there is nothing wrong with `async function xy()`.

Comment: @DanFromGermany I can agree with the first part (I didn't take a look at the referenced question), but according the second part, you say this `class A { async function xy(){} }` is a valid JavaScript code?

Comment: @DanFromGermany But it's inside a class definition! Take a look at [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Comment: You are right, just found it! I think OP's code and his issue do not fit together. The code he presents is not the code he runs.

Answer (score -1):

In the callback of any event you your `this` never points to your class. try this.

```
var self = this;
eventEmitter.on('handRaised', (question) => {
  console.log(question);
  self.whiteboard.write(question);
});
```

Comment: Not quite correct with [arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions): An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although **without its own bindings to the `this`**, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target` keywords.